# how to make callback in activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i have 3 activities

A activity has a button . On click of that button a scan happens (a continuous porcess)  and after time it gives a callback to onreceive method.

Onreceiving the call back B activity is started . B is singleTask instance . It shows a list .

On clicking of any of the item in list in B  , next the  C activity starts.{startactivity(Cintent)}

In mean time , when again a call back comes in A , due to continuous result of scan , it starts B activity , But since B is single task , so new instance is not created and it smoothly shows the updated list.

Problem is when , user is in page C , and A gets a callback , it triggers B start Activty and B seeing the current activity running (checking activty manager) to be C , triggers C , but this time  C is again created  (new instance launched ) despite C also being Singletask .

I donot want C to be again created , i want to use the same older instance .

A (Main Launcher) -> B (SingleTask)  -> C(SingleTask)

**

- Code snippet

**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button connectButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Connect);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    connectButton.setEnabled(true);
}


public void onClick(final View v) {
final Intent B = new Intent(context,B.class);
// start a specific job and wait for the callback 
}

// on receiving the call back result start activity of B
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context c, final Intent intent) {
startActivity(B);

   }
}
```

Now B Activity shows a list onstart and when clicked on any item in list it navigate to C .

```
public class B extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.B_list);
            final Context context = this;
    // Create Intent for C
    intentCList = new Intent(context,
            C.class);
     }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void putintoListVIew(Intent intent) {

BList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  startactivity(intentCList);
  }
}
```

ANdroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.broadcom.wiced.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.broadcom.wiced.RouterListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:launchMode="singleTask">

    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.broadcom.wiced.WicedListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in A activity boolean flag isActive and make it true onResume and false onPause.
When activity A get callback, you can check is it active and decide need to run B or not.

Comment: sorry . may be my explaination was not proper . i can decide with onstart and onresume and with flags , but my problem is something else . completely different .


A-> B (singleTask)->C(singleTask)..... but C is not being SingleTask ... on repeatative callback from A to B  , B is not recreated , but from B to C ,C is again recreated .. 

how to stop that and retain only one activyt window for C , so that every time on startactivty(CIntent) new instance of C is not called from B

Answer (score 0):

Make your Activity B and Activity C as singleTop. This way even if they are already launched, the same instances will be put on top.

Comment: I tried with Single top , singleTask , single instance ..

with single task -- B is singleton but when i staractivty C , evry time onstart of C is getting called . but i made both as singletask

with singletop -- in callback every time both B and C is created with new instance 

with singleInstance -- both B and C has single instance but when i navigate to C .. i am not able to go back to B . on clikcing back it again reopens C  . also the list is not refreshing in C  . also after closing the application also , B activity comes up !!!